# Form not posting Button name/value

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<form action="actions/add_cat.php" method="post" id="rtf" name="">
    <input type="text" name="cat_title" id="cat_title" required="required" placeholder="Category Title"/>

    <br /><br />


    <button type="button" onclick="button_click('#d31b26');" value="d31b26" name="cat_color"><div class="redSelect"></div></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="button_click('#f9c04c');" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c"><div class="yellowSelect"></div></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="button_click('#72bce9');" name="cat_color" value="#72bce9"><div class="blueSelect"></div></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="button_click('#ec9292');" name="cat_color" value="#ec9292"><div class="pinkSelect"></div></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="button_click('#b7d04e');" name="cat_color" value="#b7d04e"><div class="greenSelect"></div></button>    


    <div class="indexBox">
        <div class="indexBoxHeader" id="box">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="font-size: 2em;"></i></div>
        <div class="indexBoxFooter">
            <div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <br><br> 
    <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Category" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

If i test using a text input and using the cat_color name it will post that entry but when using the above it does not seem to to take the item I am selecting?

Here is the post query incase you need to see it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cat_list (cat_title, cat_color) VALUES ('".$_POST["cat_title"]."', '".$_POST["cat_color"]."')";
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a plain concatenation of $_POST["cat_title"] as one can easily craft a malicious request. See about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. You should look at mysql_real_escape_string() or/and mysql_prepare (I assume you use mysql but you find equivalents for other languages)

Comment: Ignore that for now this is for testing purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As I can't comment.*

Try to have `<radio> buttons` instead of `normal buttons`. So the php/form would understand it is and option.

Example:

```
<form .. >
   ..
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#d31b26"><div class="redSelect"></div><br>
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c"><div class="yellowSelect"></div><br>
   ..
</form>
```

**EDIT**

```
<form action="actions/add_cat.php" method="post" id="rtf" name="">
    <input type="text" name="cat_title" id="cat_title" required="required" placeholder="Category Title"/>

    <br /><br />


    <!-- Radio Buttons With customized color class -->
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#d31b26" class="redSelect"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c" class="yellowSelect"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#72bce9" class="blueSelect"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#ec9292" class="yellowSelect"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="cat_color" value="#b7d04e" class="greenSelect"><br>


    <div class="indexBox">
        <div class="indexBoxHeader" id="box">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="font-size: 2em;"></i></div>
        <div class="indexBoxFooter">
            <div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <br><br> 
    <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Category" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

Comment: May I ask what you mean by 'normal' buttons?

Comment: <button type="button" .. /> or <input type="button" .. />

Comment: If I change it to an input type the value shows itself on the button though?

Comment: Ah, I see, try using the radio buttons, and then put the color by the side of it.

Comment: And can you post how you get the values from the post please.

Comment: Really didnt wanna use radio buttons as require some styling issues

Comment: Well, instead of using div styled, you could use just the radio buttons styled. And would also short a little your code.

Comment: How do you style radios to be multiple colours though?

Comment: You don't, but as you have 5 div's with differente classes, you can do the same in the radio buttons.

Comment: Hmm I am trying but not sure how, can you show me form my code above?

Comment: That doesn't work though? the backgrounds become transparent and the radio buttons still exist

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to adapt your old css class to radio button way, they are a little different. Have a look at this link: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Comment: I have found a better way I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

So in the in the end I just wrapped a hidden field inside the div for my colour picker like so:

```
<div class="redSelect" onclick="button_click('#d31b26');"><input  type="hidden" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c" ></div>
<div class="yellowSelect" onclick="button_click('#f9c04c');" ><input type="hidden" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c" ></div>
<div class="blueSelect" onclick="button_click('#72bce9');"><input type="hidden" name="cat_color" value="#72bce9" ></div>
<div class="pinkSelect" onclick="button_click('#ec9292');"><input type="hidden" name="cat_color" value="#ec9292"></div>
<div class="greenSelect" onclick="button_click('#b7d04e');"><input type="hidden" name="cat_color" value="#b7d04e" ></div>
```

works a treat and posts out the value of the hidden field

Answer (score -1):

With me, happened that my form had so so many inputs that it simply didn't send the last ones (the button and some others). In some way, there is a "limit" on how much data you may send by POST.

Then, I put a hidden input in the upper part of the form with the same name of button and it worked .